# Helm Override not taking in Env specific application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-helm

i am deploying my springboot application docker image on GCP by using helm charts .For env specific configuration i use helm-override.yaml file.However i noticed my configured values in application-stage.properties are not being taken by application.Attaching below helm chart and build.gradle files

below is project structure

````
```
xyz <br>
        settings.gradle <br>
        build.gradle <br>
        config <br>
          prod
            application-prod.properties
          stage
            application.properties
        gradle/ <br>
            wrapper/ <br>
                gradle-wrapper.jar <br>
                gradle-wrapper.properties <br>
        src/ <br>
            main/ <br>
                java/ <br>
                resources/ <br>
                    application.properties <br>
        xyzcharts/ <br>
          values.yaml <br>
          config/ <br>
            stage/ <br>
              helm-override-stage.yaml <br>
          templates/ <br>
            configmap.yaml <br>
            cronjob.yaml <br>
            
          
```
````

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version "${springBootVersion}"
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'org.sonarqube' version "3.3"
    id 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib' version "${jibVersion}"
}

group = 'com.vsi.postgrestoattentive'

if (!project.hasProperty('buildName')) {
    throw new GradleException("Usage for CLI:" 
        + System.getProperty("line.separator") 
        + "gradlew <taskName> -Dorg.gradle.java.home=<java-home-dir> -PbuildName=<major>.<minor>.<buildNumber> -PgcpProject=<gcloudProject>"
        + System.getProperty("line.separator")
        + "<org.gradle.java.home> - OPTIONAL if available in PATH"
        + System.getProperty("line.separator")
        + "<buildName> - MANDATORY, example 0.1.23")
        + System.getProperty("line.separator")
        + "<gcpProject> - OPTIONAL, project name in GCP";
}

project.ext {
    buildName = project.property('buildName');
}

version = "${project.ext.buildName}"

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

apply from: 'gradle/sonar.gradle'
apply from: 'gradle/tests.gradle'
apply from: 'gradle/image-build-gcp.gradle'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:${springBootVersion}")
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.7.0'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-test:4.3.0'
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:${springBootVersion}")
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.4'
    implementation 'org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:4.1.1.RELEASE'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.14.1'
    implementation group: 'io.micrometer', name: 'micrometer-registry-datadog', version: '1.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:26.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:2.16.0'
}

bootJar {
    archiveFileName = "${project.name}.${archiveExtension.get()}"
}

springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}


test {
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.8"
}

jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn test
}

//SMS2-28: Code to make build check code coverage ratio
project.tasks["bootJar"].dependsOn "jacocoTestReport","jacocoTestCoverageVerification"
```

**cronjob.yaml**

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: {{ include "xyz.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{ include "xyz.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  schedule: "{{ .Values.schedule }}"
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 5
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 2
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          restartPolicy: Never
          containers:
            - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
              image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
              imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
              env:
              - name: POSTGRES_DB_USER_NAME
                valueFrom:
                  secretKeyRef:
                    name: xyz-feed-secret
                    key: DB_USER_NAME
              - name: POSTGRES_DB_PASSWORD
                valueFrom:
                  secretKeyRef:
                    name: xyz-feed-secret
                    key: DB_PASSWORD
              - name: POSTGRES_DB_URL
                valueFrom:
                  secretKeyRef:
                    name: xyz-feed-secret
                    key: DB_URL
              - name: POSTGRES_TO_ATTENTIVE_TOKEN
                valueFrom:
                  secretKeyRef:
                    name: xyz-feed-secret
                    key: ATTENTIVE_TOKEN
              - name: POD_NAME
                valueFrom:
                  fieldRef:
                    fieldPath: metadata.name
              - name: DD_AGENT_HOST
                valueFrom:
                  fieldRef:
                    fieldPath: status.hostIP  
              - name: DD_ENV
                value: {{ .Values.datadog.env }}
              - name: DD_SERVICE
                value: {{ include "xyz.name" . }}
              - name: DD_VERSION
                value: {{ include "xyz.AppVersion" . }}
              - name: DD_LOGS_INJECTION
                value: "true"
              - name: DD_RUNTIME_METRICS_ENABLED
                value: "true"
              volumeMounts:
                - mountPath: /app/config
                  name: logback
              ports:
                - name: http
                  containerPort: {{ .Values.service.port }}
                  protocol: TCP
          volumes:
            - configMap:
                name: {{ include "xyz.name" . }}
              name: logback
      backoffLimit: 0
    metadata:
      {{ with .Values.podAnnotations }}
    annotations:
      {{ toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
    labels:
      {{ include "xyz.selectorLabels" . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
```

**configmap.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ include "xyz.name" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "xyz.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
data:
  application.properties: |-
    {{- range .Files.Lines .Values.application.configoveride }}
    {{ . }}{{ end }}
  logback-spring.xml: |+
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
        <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
        <include resource="org/springframework/cloud/gcp/logging/logback-json-appender.xml" />
        <property name="projectId" value="${projectId:-${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}}"/>
        <appender name="CONSOLE_JSON" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
                <layout class="org.springframework.cloud.gcp.logging.StackdriverJsonLayout">
                    <projectId>${projectId}</projectId>
                    <includeTraceId>true</includeTraceId>
                    <includeSpanId>true</includeSpanId>
                    <includeLevel>true</includeLevel>
                    <includeThreadName>true</includeThreadName>
                    <includeMDC>true</includeMDC>
                    <includeLoggerName>true</includeLoggerName>
                    <includeFormattedMessage>true</includeFormattedMessage>
                    <includeExceptionInMessage>false</includeExceptionInMessage>
                    <includeContextName>true</includeContextName>
                    <includeMessage>true</includeMessage>
                    <includeException>true</includeException>
                    <jsonFormatter
                       class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatter">
                    </jsonFormatter>
                </layout>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE_JSON"/>
        </root>
    </configuration>
```

**values.yaml**

```
# Default values for postgres_to_attentive_product_catalog.
# This is a YAML-formatted file.
# Declare variables to be passed into your templates.

###SMS2-40 - replica count indicates no of instances we need
### - If we want 3 intances then we will metion 3 -then 3 pods will be created on server
### - For staging env we usually keep 1
replicaCount: 1

image:
###SMS2-40 - Below is image name which is created duuring build-->GCP Build image
### --->We can also give local Image details also here
### --->We can create image in Docker repository and use that image URL here
  repository: gcr.io/mgcp-1308657-vsi-operations/smscatalogfeed
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  # Overrides the image tag whose default is the chart appVersion.
  tag: ""

imagePullSecrets: []
nameOverride: ""
fullnameOverride: ""

serviceAccount:
  # Specifies whether a service account should be created
  create: true
  # Annotations to add to the service account
  annotations: {}
  # The name of the service account to use.
  # If not set and create is true, a name is generated using the fullname template
  
  name: "smscatalogfeed"

podAnnotations: {}

podSecurityContext: {}
  # fsGroup: 2000

securityContext: {}
  # capabilities:
  #   drop:
  #   - ALL
  # readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
  # runAsNonRoot: true
  # runAsUser: 1000

schedule: "56 17 * * *"

###SMS2-40 - There are 2 ways how we want to serve our applications-->1st->LoadBalancer or 2-->NodePort
service:
  type: NodePort
  port: 8087
  liveness: /actuator/health/liveness
  readiness: /actuator/health/readiness
###service:
###  type: ClusterIP
###  port: 80

restartPolicy: "Never"

ingress:
  enabled: false
  className: ""
  annotations: {}
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  hosts:
    - host: chart-example.local
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  tls: []
  #  - secretName: chart-example-tls
  #    hosts:
  #      - chart-example.local

resources: {}
  # We usually recommend not to specify default resources and to leave this as a conscious
  # choice for the user. This also increases chances charts run on environments with little
  # resources, such as Minikube. If you do want to specify resources, uncomment the following
  # lines, adjust them as necessary, and remove the curly braces after 'resources:'.
  # limits:
  #   cpu: 100m
  #   memory: 128Mi
  # requests:
  #   cpu: 100m
  #   memory: 128Mi

autoscaling:
  enabled: false
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 100
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 80
  # targetMemoryUtilizationPercentage: 80

nodeSelector: {}

tolerations: []

affinity: {}
###SMS2-40 - Below command is used to override configuration with config/application.properties
application:
  configoveride: "config/application.properties"
```

**helm-override-stage.yaml**

```
replicaCount: 1
#SMS2-12 : mgcp-1308657-vsi-operations is our server/project in GCP
image:
  repository: gcr.io/mgcp-1308657-vsi-operations/smscatalogfeed
  tag: <IMAGE_TAG_PLACEHOLDER_TO_BE_REPLACED>
application:
  configoveride: "config/stage/application-stage.properties"
datadog:
  enabled: true
  env: stage
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are many problems with your project structure and your yaml configs:

1. `application-stage.properties` file is missing;
2. Other chart files like `Chart.yaml`, `_helpers.tpl` are not reflected in your project structure;
3. `secret.yaml` is missing for your chart template, but used in your CronJob **jobTemplate** envs fetching with **secretKeyRef**;
4. Your `application-stage.properties` file is only stored in a `configmap.yaml`;
5. Your `configmap.yaml` data is defined with filename as key and file content as value, which is not suited for exposing as container environment variables.

So as to the question why `configured values in application-stage.properties are not being taken by application`, the reason is that you defined your CronJob container to fetch envs from a secret which is missing. You only have your `application-stage.properties` stored in a configmap as file, not key-value pairs.

The tutorial: [spring boot application.properties in kubernetes](https://pushbuildtestdeploy.com/spring-boot-application.properties-in-kubernetes/) may provide you more guidelines.